# Remove http referer host and other info about site in ajax-requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to remove referer or host or other information of the current site when doing an ajax-request?

This is what I've tried so far with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $.appData.edit_item_ajax_url,
    data: ajax_params,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Host', 'This gets owerwritten');
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Referer', 'This gets owerwritten');
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Test-param', 'This is fine...');
    }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    debug( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

But sadly, it does not work.

Comment: the fact you can't do it ought to be suggesting to you that it's a bad idea...

Comment: Well, I will have to do it through a proxy then.

Comment: And why don't answer the question? I was not asking if it was a bad idea or not. Some rare situations may benefit from this opportunity. E.g.: Not in "production", but when prototyping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with javascript. You can always use a proxy.